# Looking for a detailed explanation of the sos DumpStack command output

Tags: .net, debugging, clr, windbg, sos

Specifically, given the following line:

```
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
000000001d58df70 000007fe9d7a1d7d (MethodDesc 000007fe9b4205d0 +0x2dd DataSvc.Reports.ReportBase.RenderReportInternal())
```

I would like to know the exact meaning of all the numbers one can see there.

I am not looking for superficial statements like *Child-SP value is the pointer to the call stack frame created for the invocation of the method in question*. I need to know the exact layout of this frame, especially where is the `this` value (for all I know it may be in a register, which one?)

[Tess'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) blog seems to be very relevant, but it has a wealth of information and I failed to find what I am looking for there. If she has an entry dedicated to this subject - by all means, that could be the answer.

Comment: I've usually found `this` in register rcx so `!do @rcx` suffices. BUT, this is only reliable at the very beginning of the function because the function may reuse rcx. So if I want to rely on this technique then I set a breakpoint on the first instruction of the function.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a dump, not a live process.

Comment: Then you may be able to find where this lives in memory by digging backwards through the call sequence. `ub 000007fe9d7a1d7d` will show you how the caller set up the args before making the call. If rcx is set by the caller, then you may get lucky in that it's assigned from a register or memory location that is still valid. You may have to search backwards like this multiple times until finding it. Also, see "Reconstructing parameters from x64 crash dumps" at http://analyze-v.com/?p=482